# Second wxToolbar is not shown under Linux

Tags: wxwidgets

Based on the toolbar-example I have added a second toolbar to my application:

```
g_toolBar2=new wxToolBar(g_custFrame, wxID_ANY,
                         wxDefaultPosition,wxDefaultSize,
                         wxTB_FLAT|wxTB_DOCKABLE|wxTB_TEXT|wxTB_RIGHT);
<add tools here>
g_toolBar2->Realize();
```

Beside of that in a size-event the underyling elements are moved/sized to not to overlap with this toolbar.

This code works fine with Windows, I can see my toolbar docked on the right side below of the upper, horizontal toolbar

Under Linux there is a problem: I can see a grey, vertical strip where the second toolbar should appear, but none of the tools. But when I undock this toolbar (or better: when I undock this grey strip), all the tools are available in the floating toolbar.

Any idea what could be different in Linux?

Thanks!

Comment: what wx version? Is sample works for you? And what do you mean by `undocking`?

Comment: @Igor wx 3.0 (the version that is shipped with Ubuntu) and "undocking" means klicking the toolbar and pulling it away fro mthe parent frame (due to wxTB_DOCKABLE)

Comment: does sample works for you?

Comment: @Igor: the sample shows the second, vertical toolbar on the left side while the problem appears on the right side.

Comment: the sample has a menu item to place it on the right side.

Comment: @Igor the sample places the first toolbar in the right side but not the second. and the problem I describe appears with the second toolbar, not with the first.

Comment: can you make second toolbar to appear on the right side? Also, what is your `GTK+` full version? What WM? X11 or Wayland?

Comment: @Igor the example shown above _is_ the second toolbar I try to create! Everything exactly according to the sample except the position. GTK is the version that comes with Ubuntu 12.04LTS and X11 is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meanwhile found the reason for the problem:

Creating additional toolbars in wxWidgets consists of two parts:

- creation of the toolbar itself, here any toolbar that is not the first one, is *not* added via SetToolBar()
- chaging the layout of the underlying UI elements so that the additional toolbar does not overlap them in a weird way; in the toolbar example this is done within LayoutChildren()

And this LayoutChildren() is the problem: there for calculating the underlying elements the size of the toolbar itself is needed which is fetched via GetSize(). Using Windows this works correct and the toolbars size is returned. Using Linux the returned width of the toolbar is always 2. So here one has to force the toolbar to a more reasonable size.

I simply took the height of the first toolbar and used it tho set the idth of the second toolbar.

Comment: in Linux/GTK, you don't know the size of anything until this anything is realised/drawn. There are so many factors at play there  so in general, you solution seems fine. And yes - only one toolbar is managed by the TLW as shown in the sample and its even explained somewhere in the docs.